# Can you copy a worksheet and keep a reference to the new sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to copy a sheet using VBA and keep a reference to it?  I know I can do the following to keep a reference to the new worksheet, but I have to keep track of the indices and it seems like there should already be something built in that can do it.

```
Dim newws as Worksheet
Dim oldws as Worksheet

' set oldws to whatever I need, then
oldws.Copy Before:=Worksheets(1)
Set newws = Worksheets(1)
```

But it would just be cleaner if something like this were available, like it is for the Worksheets.Add

```
' You can do this
Set newws = Worksheets.Add    

' But definitely not this, because Sheets.Copy doesn't return anything.
Set newws = oldws.Copy Before:=1
```

I suppose I could write my own function:

```
Function CopyAWorksheet(ws As Worksheet, Before As Worksheet) As Worksheet
    ws.Copy Before:=Before
    Set CopyAWorksheet = Worksheets(Before.Index - 1)
End Function
```

I could add an `After` argument and make both `Before` and `After` variants so that it would act exactly like I want, but it seems likely that I'm just missing something that's already built in to Excel VBA.  If there are interesting technical reasons that this is not possible, I would love to hear those too.

I'm using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and possibly the easiest option- when you copy sheet the new copy becomes active sheet therefore you could do it in this way:

```
oldws.Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
set newws = Activesheet
```

Comment: When I do that, I get `RunTime Error 424: Object required.`  Does this work for you?

Comment: I have added first possible solution, let me check if optional code is working for me as I wrote it off-hand without checking.

Comment: I don't think The second way works... [from the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835605.aspx), it doesn't look like `ws.Copy` returns a value, so you'd be setting `newws` to nothing.  If you can either verify that the second way **does** work or you take it out of your answer, I'll accept your answer for the ActiveSheet way, which is far better than how I was doing it.

Comment: Ups, I'm surprised, optional is not working... I will remove it.

Comment: No problem.  I was surprised that that method didn't work as well; it was the first thing I tried.

Comment: +1: Checked edits and the first one won't work. Wish there was a cleaner explanation and workaround to it. `ActiveSheet` seems like a really error-prone way to do this, but no luck with other ways, it seems. Oh well, Excel. ;)

Comment: @BK201, when writing first answer I was sure it will work like for (almost) all `methods` but not this time :(.

Comment: Trust me, been there, done that. And always it's @SiddharthRout who swoops in and gives me a beating. Meh.